# Force Subsections Headings into Title Case (AMSart class)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, amsart, section-titles

Is there any way of force the titles of subsections in the amsart to be in title case by default?  I tried this but no luck:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\titlecap}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection with lowercase letters}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103838/converting-text-to-title-case, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/how-can-i-force-text-to-be-displayed-in-title-case.

Comment: @Marijn https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/how-can-i-force-text-to-be-displayed-in-title-case only works for the apa class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why replacing `\bfseries` with `\titlecap` does not work is that `\bfseries` is a declaration that does not take an argument, whereas `\titlecap` is a macro requiring an argument.

However, this approach may work, of redefining `\@sect` to look for subsections (when `#2` = 2) and, upon finding so, replace the subsection title `#8` with `\titlecap{#8}`.  I also turned off `\bfseries` in `#6` since that seems to be what the OP wanted.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\makeatletter
\let\sv@sect\@sect
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum#2=2 
    \def\next{\sv@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{\normalfont}[#7]{\titlecap{#8}}}%
  \else
    \def\next{\sv@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#7]{#8}}%
  \fi
  \next
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection with lowercase letters}

\subsection{another test case}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for not only answering but providing a clear explaination.

Answer (score 0):

look at my code. It solves your problem by using `\uppercase`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\titlecap}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section{\uppercase{Section}}

\subsection{\uppercase{Subsection with lowercase letters}}

\end{document}
```

Hope this works.

[image]

Comment: I want it in Title case, not uppercase and I want to automate it fully.